# Calculate geometry on some features have same X and Y for start and end?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, coordinates

I did "Calculate Geometry" on a line shapefile to obtain the coordinates X and Y for the start and the end of all the lines of the shape. But some lines resulted with the same X on the start and on the end, and the same Y on the start and on the end.

If the line is crossed by other line, the X and Y that results is the X and Y of the point where the line is crossed. So X,Y are the same because it's a point.
My question now is why Calculate Geometry does that?

This is one of the affected lines:
[image]

Thsi is another line and its properties
[image: Sketch properties of one of the lines with problem]

Comment: That's pretty simple actually, assuming your question is worded as intended. A line with the same X coordinate for both start and end is simply a vertical (longitudinal in GCS) line. One with the same Y coordinate is a horizontal (a latitude or parallel in GCS). If *both* are the same, per @DanC's answer then the line starts and ends at the same point (which may or may not be incorrect). Note that calc geometry lets you do start, end, and mid points on lines. It's not clear from your question exactly how you're doing things.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of some of the affected lines, as well as the calculation results in the attribute table?

Comment: I've posted a screenshot of one of the affected lines

Comment: How many vertices does that line have (you can find this by double-clicking it during an edit session and checking the Sketch Properties window)? If it had for example three, a start, out to a point, then doubled back to its origin, I can see that result. I can also see things getting weird if it is a multi-part feature. Would it be possible to post the shapefile or an export of some of the problem records anywhere? Have you run [check geometery](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000034000000) on the file to verify everything is valid?

Comment: I runned check geometry and the results table was empty.

Comment: The screenshot you have added shows that particular line is a multi-part feature (note the Part 0 and Part 1 lists of coordinates). As such I think you can only get the xy of the centroid of that object, which is why it would return the same value for both. Your screenshot doesn't show enough of the xy fields to see the complete values and determine which points, if any, are duplicates. I count seven green/red nodes, and Part 0 has seven vertices, so either I can't make out Part 1's or they are stacked on Part 0's. It may also be 0's start is 1's end.

Comment: Is there any way to solve this problem? maybe transform the line in one part? If not, I'll find the coordinates manually for each point with this problem

Comment: That depends on the data and if creating two lines instead of one is ok for your purposes. You can Explode (Advanced Editing toolbar) or Multiparts to Singleparts (gp tool) the features and it will break those multiparts into two separate features (rows/records in attribute table, whereas right now they're one). Each feature will have identical attributes to the parent at the time of split (except maybe length, which may be recalculated depending on shapefile/geodatbase/etc).

Comment: Thank you, but I want to join these two parts of the line in one part, not separate them totaly

Comment: That would require some vertex editing. Right now the reason it is multipart is you have two separate line segments represented as a single feature. You'd have to explode the feature and add a segment between wherever the two are disconnected, either as a new line or just adding another vertex to one with continue line, then merge it all back together. Or possibly delete one of the parts if it's just directly overlapping the larger part.

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look at any those lines to see what might be going on? Their start and end points may actually be in the same place, if they were drawn incorrectly. Select one of them and zoom to it. If it shows up as a point, that's why the XY coordinates of the start and end points are the same.

Depending on the coordinate system you're using, it's also possible that a very short line may *appear* to have the same start and end points because you just aren't seeing enough digits after the decimal point in your coordinates to see the difference.

Comment: I selected some of the lines that have this problem and they are actually lines, not points.

Comment: I saw that if the line is crossed by other line, the X and Y that results is the X and Y of the point where the line is crossed. So I think that is the problem, but I don't know why it happens

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Feature Vertices to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003p000000) tool with BOTH_ENDs option checked, on your lines, that will give you start/end points of the lines. Then [Add XY Coordinates](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000032000000) to populate the resultant points with Lat / Long values.

Another way to go about your workflow.